# How to take HBASE snapshot for multiple tables

Tags: hbase

For a single table we can take Hbase Snapshot using below query

```
hbase(main):024:0>
 snapshot 'tableX', 'snapshotX'
```

May i know how to take snapshots for multiple tables.

```
hbase(main):024:0>list 'table*'
TABLE
tableA
tableB
tableC
```

Can anyone please help me how to take snapshot for the tables at once.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

this is a shell scripting question rather than hbase shell. you want to chain two commands.
you can start with `hbase shell list 'table*' > tables.txt`  then read table names one by one and send snapshot commands per row in that temporary file. please google command chaining and using for x <- xxx in file contents.

Comment: hi, i am sorry. i will correct my question. Agree that we can achieve it through shell script and loop through the table names. But i want to know that can hbase snapshot will create on one table at a time ? Or can we create on a list of mutiple tables in single command ?